# vb.net adding input language at run time

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I am looking for solution to a vb.net code that can add input language at run time on window 7. 
I am able to do it on window 10 by using Powershell script

```
$OldList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$OldList.Add("fr-fr")    
Set-WinUserLanguageList $OldList -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false -Force
```

and executing same script in my vb.net code using pipeline method as follow:

```
Dim MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
    MyRunSpace.Open()
    Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("#begin")
    MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned")
    MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("$OldList = Get-WinUserLanguageList")
    MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("$OldList.Add(" + qoute + "fr-fr"+ qoute + ")")
    MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("Set-WinUserLanguageList $OldList -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false -Force")
    MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("#end")
    Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()
    MyRunSpace.Close()
```

This code runs perfectly on window 10. However, this code gives me runtime error when i deploy my code on window7. However i havn't tested the above code on window 8 or 8.1.

I have updated my OS with window7 SP1 pack and upgraded powershell version to latest version on window7. Still code doesn't work. What i think is that these set of commands that works in powershell version 5.1 on window 10 doesn't work in older version of windows such as window 7 and even on updated version of powershell on window7.
What i need is to know if any powershell script or vb.net code that can add input language at run time to my system on following operating system.
Window7, window 8, window 8.1
Any help is greatly apperciated.